# @Query including extra // for escape character "/"" in while connecting to elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

service class:

```
String linkname = StringUtils.join(link, "\", \"");

String querylink = StringUtils.wrap(linkname, "\"");

String query = "{"+"\"linkname\":["+querylink +"]}";

res = elasticsearchRepo.getMethod(querylink, PageRequest.of(page-1, pageSize));
```

repo class :

```
@Query("{\"bool\":{\"filter\":[{\"terms\":?0}]}}")

Page<Testtables> getMethod(String query,Pageable pageable);
```

Same code was working fine with springboot-starter-data-elastcisearch version 2.2.7.RELEASE with 6.8.8  spring-data-elasticsearch (3.2.7.RELEASE parent)

but getting exception with  springboot-starter-data-elastcisearch version 2.2.14 with 7.17.11 spring-data-elastcisearch ( 4.4.14 parent)

**Exception:**

reason=Unexpected character ('' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
at [Source: [B@7192df39; line: 1, column: 31]]

Comment: String query = "{"+"\"linkname\":["+querylink +"]}";   The source code from service class includes filedname   the ?0 passed will be {"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"linkname":[test1:test"]}}]}}}'

Comment: Could it be that the double quote escaping is done for you and you don't need to add it to your code?

Comment: We tried removing but still facing similar json parse exception , So is there any other versions we can try with change of depdencies

Comment: In your case, your query should just be `@Query("{\"bool\":{\"filter\":[{\"terms\":{\"linkname\": ?0}}]}}")` and you should simply pass the `link` array of terms to getMethod and SDE will make sure to properly join the values.

Comment: Tried but no luck !!! So we suspect its issue with the @Query annotation as its trying to convert \ into \\

Comment: Which `\\` are you talking about? Do your link strings contain any backslashes? This issue solved in 5.0 maybe: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2326 ? @P.J.Meisch might have an idea as he worked on that very issue

Comment: Our previous ?0 has {"linkname":["test1:test"]}  so  to inlcude "linkname" as string we included escape charecter /

Comment: No I meant in the `test1:test` values, any potential backslashes there?

Comment: There was some issue with testing and  @Query("{\"bool\":{\"filter\":[{\"terms\":{\"linkname\": ?0}}]}}")   this approach to pass values in ?0 and rest of query as static in @Query worked for us .. Thank you so much Val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Query("{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"linkname": ?0}}]}}")

As Val Suggested in comments passing values in ?0 and rest as static string worked for us ..Thank you

we tested with springboot version is 2.7.14

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped!